# YouTube subscribe button not working

Tags: javascript, api, button, youtube, subscribe

I'm trying to add subscribe button to my web site.
I use code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/ and get this error in  console:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('http://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin ('https://www.youtube.com').

This is code, that I'm adding to page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers"></div>
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jo11q3d2/